# insertion sort : why assigning key to j+1 index?

Tags: c++, sorting

```
void insertionSort(vector<int>& v){
    for(int i =1; i<v.size(); ++i){
        int key = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while(j>=0 && key < v[j]){
            swap(v[j], v[j+1]);
            j--;
        }
        v[j+1] = key; // works fine without this.
    }
}
```

In an insertion sort algorithm, I just wonder why the commented part was inserted.
I did several experiments removing that part, and actually thought it is okay to get rid of that.

Could anyone explain of the purpose of the line? Any help would be well appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get the code from and how can you be sure it's actually correct? Have you exercised this thoroughly with that line missing?

Comment: _"I did several experiments removing that part, and actually thought it is okay to get rid of that."_ Can you explain to us, scientifically, those experiments? Show your working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since after each swap it does `j--`, after the final swap (which frees up `v[j]`), it decreases `j` once more. Hence you need to put the new element at `v[j + 1]`.

By the way, swap is not necessary for this code, you might as well do `v[j + 1] = v[j]` instead of `swap`.

**Edit**

Regarding the question on implementation, perhaps the author was making a some point which needed the `swap` - without knowing the context, we can't say for sure.

Since no one really uses insertion sort, I reckon the purpose of this was only theoretical, and likely to compute complexity by counting number of swaps. Hence the author may have been demonstrating the sort with `swap` as a building block.

Back to the question,

1. the implementation is **correct**, if you are okay with the extra writes that `swap` does.

(Essentially `swap(a, b)` is `t = a; a = b; b = t;`, so two additional writes.)

2. If you do have the `swap`, then the commented out line is indeed not necessary.

Without the `swap` you may rewrite it as -

```
void insertionSort(vector<int>& v){
    for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i){
        int key = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while(j >= 0 && key < v[j]){
            v[j + 1] = v[j];
            j--;
        }
        v[j + 1] = key;  // this is now necessary.
    }
}
```

Note that since this reduces asymptotic time taken by only a constant, complexity still remain the same as the one with `swap`, i.e. $O(n^2)$.

Comment: swap would even be incorrect for insertion sort. Lots of unnecessary extra writes.

Comment: Thank you all for comments. This codes are from a programmer's blog. I think it is wrong in many points. If you don't mind, would you let me know what is proper implementation of insertion sort in cpp?

Comment: The implementation is correct, author was possibly making a theoretical point. Alternatively you could just change the ``swap`` to an assignment - though it won't change complexity, you will get a reduction in runtime by a constant factor. Added comments directly to answer.